# Changing the color of a jquery ui slider as you slide it

Tags: css, jquery-ui, jquery-slider

I've been looking around for an answer on how to do this and I can't seem to figure it out (even looking at the jquery ui themeing documentation).  As I move the slider from left to right, I want the section on the left side of the slider-knob to change to orange (instead of the default grey).

The jquery theme-roll generated the css below. Presumably the .ui-widget-header background-color would control this, but it does't seem to.  Neither does adding a background color to any other class. Any idea how I fix this so that as you slide horizontally you get a different color?

JQUERY:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#tasks_time").slider({
            value: 1,
            min: 0,
            max: 72,
            step: 1,
            slide: function() {
                update();
            }
        });

        $("#tasks_done").slider({
            value: 5,
            min: 0,
            max: 1000,
            step: 10,
            slide: function() {
                update();
            }
        });
```

HTML:

```
    Finish these items in <span id="curr-tasks_time" class="calc_number">1</span> hours

    <div id="tasks_time">
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.ui-widget-content { border: 1px solid #ccc; background: #ff9900 url(images/ui-bg_flat_100_ff9900_40x100.png) 50% 50% repeat-x; color: #222222; }
.ui-widget-header { border: 1px solid #aaaaaa; background: #797979 url(images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_75_797979_1x100.png) 50% 50% repeat-x; color: #222222; font-weight: bold; }

.ui-slider { position: relative; text-align: left; }
.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle { position: absolute; z-index: 2; width: 1.2em; height: 1.2em; cursor: default; }
.ui-slider .ui-slider-range { position: absolute; z-index: 1; font-size: .7em; display: block; border: 0; background-position: 0 0; }

.ui-slider-horizontal { height: .8em; }
.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-handle { top: -.3em; margin-left: -.6em; }
.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-range { top: 0; height: 100%;  }
.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-range-min { left: 0;  }
.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-range-max { right: 0;}
```

Here's [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/EAaLK/)

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

ther is a example

http://jsfiddle.net/amkrtchyan/EAaLK/2/

and a jquery code......

```
          $( "#tasks_time" ).slider({
                range: "min",
                value: 37,
                min: 1,
                max: 700,
                slide: function() {
                    update();
                }
            });
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks!  Just adding the "range: 'min'" and a value for "min: " did the trick!

Comment: @RyanSammut yes it works ther is a example

http://jsfiddle.net/amkrtchyan/EAaLK/2/

Comment: @Aram Mkrtchyan - I am not seeing the slider colour change when I execute that fiddle from Google Chrome.

Answer (score 6):

```js
 $(function() {
   $( "#slider" ).slider({
       min: 0,
       max: 100,
       slide: function( event, ui ) {
                 $("#slider").css('background', 'linear-gradient(90deg, #c75f04                                                      '+ui.value+'%, #cccccc 0%)');
                  $( "#price" ).val( "$" + ui.value);
               }
    });
            
});
```

```html
<link href = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css"
         rel = "stylesheet">
<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id = "slider"></div><br>
Price : <input id="price">
```

Answer (score 5):

Aram's answer didn't work for me. Also the jsfiddle demo doesn't seem to do what it's supposed to.
Here is a more advanced version that does work, and includes multiple colors.

You can fiddle with it and set as many colors and combinations as you'd like:

The HTML:

```
<p>A Colored jQuery UI Slider</p>
<div id="coloredSlider"></div>
```

The CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#coloredSlider {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
width: 600px;
    margin: 15px;
}
#coloredSlider .ui-slider-range { 
    background: #ff0000; 
}

#coloredSlider .ui-state-default, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default {
    background: none;
    background-color: #FFF;
}
```

The Javascript:

```
function getTheColor( colorVal ) {
    var theColor = "";
    if ( colorVal < 50 ) {
                myRed = 255;
                myGreen = parseInt( ( ( colorVal * 2 ) * 255 ) / 100 );
          }
      else  {
                myRed = parseInt( ( ( 100 - colorVal ) * 2 ) * 255 / 100 );
                myGreen = 255;
          }
      theColor = "rgb(" + myRed + "," + myGreen + ",0)"; 
    return( theColor ); 
}

function refreshSwatch() {
    var coloredSlider = $( "#coloredSlider" ).slider( "value" ),
    myColor = getTheColor( coloredSlider );

    $( "#coloredSlider .ui-slider-range" ).css( "background-color", myColor );

    $( "#coloredSlider .ui-state-default, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default" ).css( "background-color", myColor );
}

$(function() {
      $( "#coloredSlider" ).slider({
            orientation: "horizontal",
            range: "min",
            max: 100,
            value: 0,
            slide: refreshSwatch,
            change: refreshSwatch
      });
});
```

DEMO: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/obWzaQ

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
.ui-widget-content { background: purple; }
```

As a bonus, if you want to change the color of the little drag handle, use this:

```
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-default { background: chartreuse; }
```