# jquery Handle and Track Style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I ma having a problem styling my sliders, i managed to change the handle to an image which worked but then the track color didnt work,

Loan Amount
Your Loan 
Loan Length

Days Loaned 
Repayment Date

Your Loan

Interest

APR

This is What i need it to look like
https://capfin.co.za/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the handle is already set to a custom image. However, it's not aligned in the center adding `background-position: -6.5px -4px;` to `#slider1 .ui-slider-handle` will make that happen.

Also the width & height of the track could be changed by applying the same to `.ui-slider` and the background colour could be changed of `.ui-widget.ui-widget-content`

Comment: Thanks for your reply

Comment: Please https://codepen.io/mdxsolutions/pen/JJbPKG The track color does not want to work for min max sliding

Comment: How do you want it to change? 1. Set to a permanent colour 2. Change its colour on slider moved

Comment: Hi Yes when it moves

Comment: the color when you move more or less

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8723633/changing-the-color-of-a-jquery-ui-slider-as-you-slide-it